# JQquery click event not working for html input(checkbox) inside asp panels

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, click

Inside an aspx file I have asp:panels under an UpdatePanel

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Panel ID="PnlTraveler" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <input id="chkBoxVisAst" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" enableviewstate="true" />
  </asp:Panel>
 <ContentTemplate>
</asp"UpdatePanel>
```

If I write my Jquery codes in the same page under the asp:Content head to work with the click event it doesn't recognize the event id in my case  chkBoxVisAst => this id.

**JQuery**

```
asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('ready', function () {
        $('#chkBoxVisAst').on('click', function ()
        {
            if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked")
            {
                alert("checked");
            } else {
                alert("unchecked");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It works if I put my input(checkbox) outside my panel. How am I going to access my event id from inside the asp:panels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your code. You cannot add any element directly inside update panel. You have to put them in **ContentTemplate**.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="PnlTraveler" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <input id="chkBoxVisAst" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" enableviewstate="true" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

After adding the code above you will be able to access the checkbox element with its ID.

**EDIT**

Add the code below,

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        $('#chkBoxVisAst').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
                alert("checked");
            } else {
                alert("unchecked");
            }
        });
    });
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Pardon me for I forgot to put it down. In my code contentTemplate was already there. If I make the basic panel visible then it gets the id but after validation of input that panel (PnlTraveler) is supposed to be visible.
I just cant get the id after the validation . (After the Panel Updates)

Comment: Update my ans above@JabedHossain

Comment: Thanks a lot brother ... It helped a lot to understand the operation